# Flutter using nearby_connections in Peer to Peer to send and Receive a Package

Tags: flutter, dart, p2p, peer, google-nearby-connections

The code I've written here seems to connect two devices when the first chooses to be the "DISCOVERER" and the other the "CONNECTOR".
When I try to execute "SEND PACKAGE", it says that the Payload was sent, but the other device does absolutely nothing.

For this project, I'm using 
https://pub.dev/packages/nearby_connections (3.1.0)
https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler (8.3.0)
The peer-to-peer strategy, in this case, is P2P_CLUSTER. (Different strategies can be found here
https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/strategies)

idFriend ist at the start 0. Later it will override it on each device as the EndPointId on each device. 
The device which is the connector has username 2. 
The device which is the discoverer has the username 1.

Separately I've added code below like acceptpackage() and sendpack(). sendpack() seems to work, while acceptpackage() doesn't actually accept it, especially as acceptpackage() is already in the code of connect().

```dart
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:nearby_connections/nearby_connections.dart';
import 'package:permission_handler/permission_handler.dart';

final String connector_userName = "2";
final String discoverer_userName = "1";
final Strategy strategy = Strategy.P2P_CLUSTER;

class peerwidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _peerwidgetState createState() => _peerwidgetState();
}

String mytext = "";

class _peerwidgetState extends State<peerwidget> {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
          title: const Text("Somecrab", textDirection: TextDirection.ltr),
          actions: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
                icon: const Icon(Icons.settings),
                onPressed: () {
                  print("OPENING SETTINGS FOR BACKGROUND COLOR AND SUCH");
                }),
          ]),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Container(
            child: Text(mytext),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size(140, 50),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("location");
              //setstate oderso, nächsts Bild holle
              locationpermission();
            },
            child: Column(
              // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                Text("Ask location"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size(140, 50),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("storage");
              //setstate oderso, nächsts Bild holle
              storagepermission();
            },
            child: Column(
              // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                Text("Ask storage"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size(140, 50),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("Kill all");
              //setstate oderso, nächsts Bild holle
              closeall();
            },
            child: Column(
              // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                Text("Kill all"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size(140, 50),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("CONNECT");
              //setstate oderso, nächsts Bild holle

              setState(() {
                connect();
              });
            },
            child: Column(
              // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                Text("CONNECT"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size(140, 50),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("DISCOVER");
              //setstate oderso, nächsts Bild holle
              setState(() {
                discover();
              });
            },
            child: Column(
              // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                Text("DISCOVER"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size(140, 50),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("SEND PACKAGE");
              //setstate oderso, nächsts Bild holle
              setState(() {
                sendpack();
              });
            },
            child: Column(
              // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                Text("SEND PACKAGE"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          ElevatedButton(
            style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
              minimumSize: const Size(140, 50),
            ),
            onPressed: () {
              print("ACCEPT PACKAGE");
              //setstate oderso, nächsts Bild holle
              setState(() {
                acceptpackage();
              });
            },
            child: Column(
              // Replace with a Row for horizontal icon + text
              children: const <Widget>[
                Icon(Icons.arrow_forward),
                Text("ACCEPT PACKAGE"),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}

onConnectionInitiated() {
  mytext = "onConnectionInitiated";
}

onConnectionResult() {
  mytext = "onConnectionResult";
}

onDisconnected() {
  mytext = "onConnectionDisconnected";
}

onEndpointFound(String id, String username, String serviceId) {
  mytext = "Found: " + id + username + serviceId;
}

onEndpointLost() {
  mytext = "onEndpointLost";
}

bool connectionexists = false;
//var theendpointid = "1";
String idFriend = "0";
connect() async {
  print("connecting started...");
  mytext = "connection started";
  try {
    await Nearby().startAdvertising(
      connector_userName,
      strategy,
      onConnectionInitiated: (String id, ConnectionInfo info) {
        print("[CONNECTION INITIATED]: \n ID: " +
            id +
            " info: " +
            info.toString());
        idFriend = id;

        Nearby().acceptConnection(id, onPayLoadRecieved: (endpointId, payload) {
          print("[ACCEPT CONNECTION]: \n EndpointID: " +
              endpointId +
              " Payload: " +
              payload.toString());
          // called whenever a payload is recieved.
        }, onPayloadTransferUpdate: (endpointId, payloadTransferUpdate) {
          print("[PAYLOAD TRANSFER UPDATE]: \n endpointId: " +
              endpointId +
              " PayloadTransferUpdate: " +
              payloadTransferUpdate.toString());
          // gives status of a payload
          // e.g success/failure/in_progress
          // bytes transferred and total bytes etc
        });
      },
      onConnectionResult: (String id, Status status) {
        print("[CONNECTION RESULT] \n ID: " +
            id +
            " status: " +
            status.toString());
        // Called when connection is accepted/rejected
      },
      onDisconnected: (String id) {
        print("[DISCONNECTED] \n ID: " + id);
        // Callled whenever a discoverer disconnects from advertiser
        onDisconnected();
      },
      serviceId: "com.simon.fluttershit", // uniquely identifies your app
    );
  } catch (PlatformException) {
    print("exception at 187");
    print("insufficient permissions or some error!");
    // platform exceptions like unable to start bluetooth or insufficient permissions
  }
}

discover() async {
  //print("the connection existance is:" + connectionexists.toString());
  mytext = "discovery started";
  //Does it stay within this loop because await? No.

  /*if (connectionexists == false) {*/
  try {
    await Nearby().startDiscovery(
      discoverer_userName,
      strategy,
      onEndpointFound: (String id, String userName, String serviceId) {
        print("[ENDPOINT FOUND]: \n ID: " +
            id +
            " userName: " +
            userName +
            " serviceId: " +
            serviceId +
            "\n");
        print("WAS CONNECTED TO: " + discoverer_userName);

        try {
          Nearby().requestConnection(
            userName,
            id,
            onConnectionInitiated: (id, info) {
              print("[CONNECTION INITIATED]: \n ID: " +
                  id +
                  " Info: " +
                  info.toString());
              connectionexists = true;
              idFriend = id;
            },
            onConnectionResult: (id, status) {
              print("[CONNECTION RESULT]: \n" + id + " " + status.toString());
            },
            onDisconnected: (id) {
              print("[DISCONNECTED]: \n" + id);
              connectionexists = false;
            },
          );
        } catch (PlatformException) {
          print("exception at 187");
          print("insufficient permissions or some error!");
        }
      },
      serviceId: "com.simon.fluttershit",
      onEndpointLost: (String? endpointId) {
        print("[ENDPOINT LOST]: \n" + endpointId.toString());
      }, // uniquely identifies your app
    );
  } catch (PlatformException) {
    print("exception at 187");
    print("insufficient permissions or some error!");
    // platform exceptions like unable to start bluetooth or insufficient permissions
  }
  /*} else {
    print("please disconnect first!");
  }*/
}

void sendpack() {
  List<int> data = [102, 111, 114, 116, 121, 45, 116, 119, 111, 0];
  Uint8List bytes = Uint8List.fromList(data);
  Nearby().sendBytesPayload(idFriend, bytes);
  print("[SENDPACK]: Receiver ID: " +
      idFriend.toString() +
      "Data: " +
      bytes.toString());
}

void acceptpackage() {
  Nearby().acceptConnection(idFriend, onPayLoadRecieved: (endpointId, payload) {
    print("Something was received: EndpointId: " +
        endpointId +
        " Payload: " +
        payload.toString());
    // called whenever a payload is recieved.
  }, onPayloadTransferUpdate: (endpointId, payloadTransferUpdate) {
    print("The status of Payload is: EndPointId: " +
        endpointId +
        " PayloadTransferUpdate: " +
        payloadTransferUpdate.toString());
    // gives status of a payload
    // e.g success/failure/in_progress
    // bytes transferred and total bytes etc
  });
}

void locationpermission() {
  Nearby().askLocationPermission();
}

void storagepermission() {
  Nearby().askExternalStoragePermission();
}

void closeall() {
  connectionexists = false;
  Nearby().stopAdvertising();
  Nearby().stopDiscovery();
  Nearby().stopAllEndpoints();
}
```

Output on connector of a payload sent to discoverer:

```
I/flutter (28055): [CONNECTION INITIATED]: 
I/flutter (28055):  ID: D0ND info: Instance of 'ConnectionInfo'
I/ViewRootImpl@d507b48[MainActivity](28055): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@d507b48[MainActivity](28055): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (28055): SEND PACKAGE
D/nearby_connections(28055): sentPayload
I/flutter (28055): [SENDPACK]: Receiver ID: D0NDData: [102, 111, 114, 116, 121, 45, 116, 119, 111, 0]
D/nearby_connections(28055): ad.onConnectionResult
```

Output of discoverer sending a payload to connector:

```
I/flutter (28055): connecting started...
D/nearby_connections(28055): startAdvertising
D/nearby_connections(28055): ad.onConnectionInitiated
I/flutter (28055): [CONNECTION INITIATED]: 
I/flutter (28055):  ID: M9N3 info: Instance of 'ConnectionInfo'
I/ViewRootImpl@d507b48[MainActivity](28055): ViewPostIme pointer 0
I/ViewRootImpl@d507b48[MainActivity](28055): ViewPostIme pointer 1
I/flutter (28055): ACCEPT PACKAGE
E/flutter (28055): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Failure, 8009: STATUS_OUT_OF_ORDER_API_CALL, null, null)
E/flutter (28055): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:607:7)
E/flutter (28055): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:156:18)
E/flutter (28055): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28055): #2      Nearby.acceptConnection (package:nearby_connections/src/nearby.dart:342:12)
E/flutter (28055): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter (28055):
```

Pictures of the Program, both for discoverer and connector:
[image: Screenshot of my app]

**Please help me figure out, why the PayLoad is not being received by either the discoverer or the connector.**

Comment: Is the connection successful on both ends before you start payload transfer? https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/nearby/connection/ConnectionsStatusCodes#STATUS_OUT_OF_ORDER_API_CALL